# program that asks the user to enter the day number of the year, and the program returns the date by specifying the month and day

Tags: java, java-calendar

How i can write a program that asks the user to enter the day number of the year (assuming there are 365 days in the year) and the program returns the date by specifying the month and day. For instance,

Enter a number from 1 to 365: 100

Date: April 10

Comment: The `LocalDate` class has a static method called `ofYearDay` that does this calculation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Ievadiet skaitli no 1 lidz 365:");

```
            Scanner myScanner= new Scanner(System.in);
                    
            short skaitlis;
                    
                if(skaitlis>0 && skaitlis<=31) {        
                    System.out.println("Datums:" + skaitlis + ". janvāris");    
                }
                        
                else if(skaitlis>31 && skaitlis<=59) {          
                    skaitlis=(short) ( skaitlis - 31);              
                    System.out.println("Datums: "+ skaitlis + ". februāris");
                }
                        
                else if(skaitlis>59 && skaitlis<=90) {
                    skaitlis=(short) ( skaitlis -59 );
                    System.out.println("Datums: "+ skaitlis + ". marts");
                }           
                else if(skaitlis>90 && skaitlis<=120) {         
                    skaitlis=(short) ( skaitlis - 90);
                    System.out.println("Datums: "+ skaitlis + ". aprīlis");         
                }           
                else if(skaitlis>120 && skaitlis<=151) {
                    skaitlis=(short) ( skaitlis - 120);
                    System.out.println("Datums: "+ skaitlis + ". maijs");       
                }               
                else if(skaitlis>151 && skaitlis<=181) {
                    skaitlis=(short) ( skaitlis - 151);
                    System.out.println("Datums: "+ skaitlis + ". jūnijs");      
                }
                else if(skaitlis>181 && skaitlis<=212) {
                    skaitlis=(short) ( skaitlis - 181);
                    System.out.println("Datums: "+ skaitlis + ". jūlijs");
                }
                else if(skaitlis>212 && skaitlis<=243) {
                    skaitlis=(short) ( skaitlis - 212);
                    System.out.println("Datums: "+ skaitlis + ". augusts");
                }
                else if(skaitlis>243 && skaitlis<=273) {
                    skaitlis=(short) ( skaitlis - 243);
                    System.out.println("Datums: "+ skaitlis + ". septembris");
                }
                else if(skaitlis>273 && skaitlis<=304) {
                    skaitlis=(short) ( skaitlis - 273);
                    System.out.println("Datums: "+ skaitlis + ". oktobris");
                }
                else if(skaitlis>304 && skaitlis<=334) {
                    skaitlis=(short) ( skaitlis - 304);
                    System.out.println("Datums: "+ skaitlis + ". novembris");
                }
                else if(skaitlis>334 && skaitlis<=365) {
                    skaitlis=(short) ( skaitlis - 334);
                    System.out.println("Datums: "+ skaitlis + ". decembris");
                }
                else {
        System.out.println("incorekt");
                }
                    
            
}
```